# How to update and delete comment base on user in node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on blog mern stack project with comment feature, each user was able to create comment on the post, but I don't know how to enable the **update & delete** comment base on the user id & their comment because each user can only delete or update their own comment only not the other. Any idea would appreciate.

This is my route but each user can update or delete other comment of other that's not what I want.

````
router.put('/event/:cmt_id/comment', userAuthorization, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { cmt_id } = req.params;
    const postedBy = req.userId;
    const comment = await CommentSchema.findById({ _id: cmt_id });
    console.log(comment);
    if (comment._id) {
      await CommentSchema.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: cmt_id }, req.body, {
        new: true,
      });
      return res.json({ status: 'success', message: 'Comment updated' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({ status: 'error', message: error.message });
  }
});
const commentSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    writer: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    responseTo: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    event: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Event',
    },
    text: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);```
````

Comment: Just add another filter to find method: `CommentSchema.findOne({ $and: [{ _id: cmt_id }, { writer: postedBy }]);`

Comment: Thank you so much man, it actually worked.